# How to copy files with only 1 extension and not double in command prompt

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, pscp

I need to copy only `.jpg` and not `.jpg.jpg` from a particular folder.

When I do a `copy c:\data\*.jpg D:\backup\` both `.jpg` and `.jpg.jpg` named files are copied over and I'm not sure how to omit the double extension named files from the copy operation.

**Note:** I'm not allowed to rename or delete those `.jpg.jpg` files

Comment: Rather than employ sophisticated sync products, it might be simpler to copy all the `.jpg` files and then delete the `.jpg.jpg` ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using powershell instead of command prompt:

```
Copy-Item C:\data*.jpg -Destination D:\backup -Exclude "*.jpg.jpg"
```

This is of course assuming that you have a lot of files named `data[something].jpg` in C: and not a directory tree with images in it.

If you want a recursive copy of `jpg`s in C:\Data\ without files ending in `.jpg.jpg`:

```
$source = 'C:\data'
$dest = 'D:\backup'
$exclude = @('*.jpg.jpg')
Get-ChildItem $source -Recurse -Exclude $exclude -Filter *.jpg | Copy-Item -Destination {Join-Path $dest $_.FullName.Substring($source.length)}
```

(shamefully stolen and modified from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/732316/4022608))

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [for](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html) loop to iterate files in the directory and use  [variable substitutions](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) to check that each iterated "*file name part only without it's own extension*" does not contain another extension (`.jpg`). Files that do not contain an additional extension within their file name will be copied with the [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) command using conditional [if](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html) logic accordingly.

### Batch Script

```
@ECHO ON

SET "srcPath=c:\data"
SET "copyPath=D:\backup"

for %%a in ("%srcPath%\*.jpg") do (
    for %%b in ("%%~dpna") do if [%%~xb]==[] XCOPY /F /Y "%%~a" "%copyPath%\"
    )
PAUSE
EXIT
```

---

### Further Resources

- [For](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)
- **Variable Substitutions (FOR /?)**

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > ```
- [If](https://ss64.com/nt/if.html)
- [XCOPY](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html)